# mock setup with array parameter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I have an issue with Mocking methods Please see below:

This is the interface

```
public interface IShop
{
    string CheckNames(string[] names);
}
```

Here is my Mock

```
var names = "A,B,C";
var shopMock = new Mock<IShop>(MockBehavior.Strict);
shopMock.Setup(s => s.CheckNames(names.Split(','))).Returns("GoodNames");
```

However when I call this method in my test, this method is failed with Moq.MockException : IShop.CheckNames(["A", "B", "C"]) invocation failed with mock behavior Strict.

```
var obj = shopMock.Object;
Assert.AreEqual("GoodNames", obj.CheckNames(names.Split(',')));
```

To make it work, I need to

```
var names = "A,B,C";
var shopMock = new Mock<IShop>(MockBehavior.Strict);

var nameList = names.Split(',');

shopMock.Setup(s => s.CheckNames(nameList)).Returns("GoodNames");

var obj = shopMock.Object;
Assert.AreEqual("GoodNames", obj.CheckNames(names.Split(',')));
```

Why I need to create nameList here to make it to work? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems, that in first case test will fail, because two calls of `names.Split(',')` return different references for result `string[]` and mock setup and `Assert` are called with different object. You should use [`It.Is` expression to setup mock](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#matching-arguments) accepting any array with `A`, `B`, `C` values for `CheckNames` in first case

```cs
var names = "A,B,C";
            
var shopMock = new Mock<IShop>(MockBehavior.Strict);
shopMock.Setup(s =>
        s.CheckNames(It.Is<string[]>(_ => _.SequenceEqual(names.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.None)))))
    .Returns("GoodNames");
var obj = shopMock.Object;
Assert.Equal("GoodNames", obj.CheckNames(names.Split(',')));
```

Or use the same array for `Setup` and `Assert` methods, which seems to be done in your second case (but full sample is missing)

```cs
var names = "A,B,C";
var nameList = names.Split(',');

var shopMock = new Mock<IShop>(MockBehavior.Strict);
shopMock.Setup(s => s.CheckNames(nameList)).Returns("GoodNames");
var obj = shopMock.Object;
Assert.Equal("GoodNames", obj.CheckNames(nameList));
```

Comment: This is the second case and it works in this way too.  var names = "A,B,C";
            var shopMock = new Mock<IShop>(MockBehavior.Strict);
            var list = names.Split(',');
            shopMock.Setup(s => s.CheckNames(list)).Returns("GoodNames");

            var obj = shopMock.Object;
            Assert.AreEqual("GoodNames", obj.CheckNames(names.Split(',')));

Comment: Not sure why it works with Assert.AreEqual("GoodNames", obj.CheckNames(names.Split(','))); if the setup is on a different array object

Comment: @Helic which Moq and .NET version are you using? `s => s.CheckNames(names.Split(','))` will raise _An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments_ error in my end

Comment: I am using Moq 4.7.99 and .net 4.6.2.